# Symfony 3 / sonata_type_collection change query each add row

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

I'm using the Sonata Admin and currently trying to get me to be able to change my query to every click event in the sonata_type_collection.

I have the 'Variation' entity in which it contains the collection type in the form to call the entity 'Value'.

However, this 'Value' entity contains an auto relationship to reference parent values ​and child values ​ex: (Id 1 does not contain any parent, so its field will be null, but id 2 contains a parent value, putting id 1 in the parent field parent).

The idea was that with each click that was given to add a new row of values, check the previous row and perform a new query to bring only the "child values".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the SonataMediaBundle and SonataClassificationBundle source code it seems there is a similar case like you described.